# Importing IDL sav file into Mathematica

Tags: import, binary

I have a rather big (around 400 MB) file written by the IDL (Interactive Data Language) software into its binary format ".SAV" which is a proprietary format, not the spss format expected by Mathematica for .sav files.
I wish to process the data using Mathematica, not IDL (which I do not possess, by the way), but I have to read them beforehand.
The only workaround I found to access the data, so far, is reading them into MATLAB (using the  restore_idl function) but then I have still the problem of a space-effective way of converting this big chunk of data into a format readable by Mathematica.
I thank in advance for any suggestion
Fabio

Comment: What is in the data? That might help deciding what format might be most effective to store it in transit. Would HDF5 format be a viable option? You could also take a look at this [Listing of All Formats](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfAllFormats.html) for inspiration.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this format, but it seems `Python`'s `scipy` [can read this format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.readsav.html). Either use python to convert it to a format Mathematica supports or use `ExternalEvaluate` directly. If it did work, please post your workflow as an answer, so future readers like you could use it.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I solved the problem using the same guidelines proposed by Ben Izd, but for the fact that used matlab rather than Python: first convert data from idl' s .sav to matlab's .mat file. Then, import the .mat file into Mathematica using the simple "Import" function.
Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Thanks for updating the status of your question. Can you please add some code and conversion details to this answer (perhaps for a much smaller but representative dataset)? Or can you convert your answer to a comment?

Comment: Well, actually the procedure is just three-step: 1) Import data in matlab using the function "restore_idl" available at https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43899-restore_idl, 2) write the data in a standard matlab .mat file; 3) read the .mat file into Mathematica using Import[filename,{"MAT","Data"}]